# Proving OLS estimator of variance

Tags: estimation, least-squares, variance

According to Gujarati, author notes that in a simple linear equation form $Y_i=\alpha +\beta X_i + \epsilon_i$ where regression model is defined as $\hat Y_i =\hat \alpha + \hat \beta X_i$ OLS method gives us the following:

$$E[(\hat \beta - \beta)\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x)(u_i - \bar u)] = \sigma^2$$

However, I can't understand why that equation is true if $E(\hat \beta) = E(\beta) = \beta$? Shouldn't we receive $0$ there when we take estimated values of betas as one can re-write this as: $$\beta E[\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x)(u_i - \bar u)] - \beta E[\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x)(u_i - \bar u)]$$

What kind of mistake I make while deriving this form? Can you please clarify?

P.S. This equation is used later to calculate that $E(\sum_{i=1}^n \hat u_i^2) = (n-2)\sigma$

Comment: In general $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$ only when $X,Y$ are uncorrelated. Independ works, too. But in your case they aren't

Comment: That's true indeed - but I have $E(X - Y)$, not $E(XY)$

Comment: But how do you bring $\hat \beta $ outside the expectation?

Comment: Am I right then saying that $\hat \beta$ is dependent upon the population ($x_i$), while $\beta$ is just a fixed number not dependent upon anything?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: Ok, got it - please write an answer and I will mark it as a solution then

Comment: Done ;-) glad to have helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot bring the random variable $\hat \beta$ outside of the expectation because it is not uncorrelated with the $X_i$.